# How to start a background task when chrome fires up for a chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am creating a chrome app (packaged) and I have to create a socket and listen for the incoming broadcast messages as soon as chrome browser starts up.

I came across  [this API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup) , but it seems to be only for extensions.

And also [the API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onCreated)  for listening when a window is created needs the permission

`"permissions": ["tabs"],` and this also is available only for extensions.

So is this possible for a chrome app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.onStartup` is also available to the Chrome Apps (it is listed as supported api on Chrome App Platform API [page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index)). So you can just use it in your chrome app.

Comment: I tried the API in background.js and adding a test console log in the callback function , but that wont show up in console log on starting the chrome. Am I missing something?

Comment: @banguru Well, it depends on how you check it. Background pages live for a short time if they do not perform any tasks. So it is better to check log messages via `Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool`. It keeps all the messages from different apps, so you should see it there (I've actually tried this, so it should be working)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Apps also have an `onStartup` event, as documented [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onStartup).

Additionally, you will likely want to handle events like [`onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onInstalled) to start your background [socket tcpServer](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer) after the app is first installed (or updated).

The `"tabs"` permission is only available to extensions, since apps are not meant to interact with the browser/webpages at all, so you certainly won't be able to use that.